# Weird behaviour when I open a reportviewer in WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, reportviewer

When I open a report in my WPF project once, I get this message this message when I exit

```
{"Error while unloading appdomain. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131015)"}
```

Stack Trace :

```
at System.AppDomain.Unload(AppDomain domain)
at Microsoft.ReportingServices.RefCountedAppDomain.Dispose()
at Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.LocalReport.ReportRuntimeSetupHandler.ReleaseSandboxAppDomain()


at Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.LocalReport.Dispose()
at Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportInfo.Dispose()
at Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportHierarchy.Clear()
at Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportViewer.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
at System.ComponentModel.Component.Finalize()
```

Is there something I do wrong ? I just open a form with a windowsFormHost and a ReportViewer inside. Do I need to close something else before closing my application ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is reported [microsoft](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/522208/wpf-app-with-reportviewer-gets-error-while-unloading-appdomain-exception-on-termination) bug. However, there is a workaround for it -
The workaround is to call

```
reportViewer.LocalReport.ReleaseSandboxAppDomain();
```

method before closing the parent form.

example :

```
private void frmMyForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
            reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReleaseSandboxAppDomain();

}
```

You can look at here for any assitance :
 http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/522208/wpf-app-with-reportviewer-gets-error-while-unloading-appdomain-exception-on-termination