# Error while unloading AppDomain. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131015)

Tags: c#

I am having this error after using ReportViewer. Upon exit it has this error. Don't know what is causing this. I am using C#.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is a [reported](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/522208/wpf-app-with-reportviewer-gets-error-while-unloading-appdomain-exception-on-termination) Microsoft bug. There is a workaround for it - to call `reportViewer.LocalReport.ReleaseSandboxAppDomain()` method before closing the parent form.

Example:

```
private void frmMyForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReleaseSandboxAppDomain();
}
```

Reference: [Weird behaviour when I open a reportviewer in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208482/weird-behaviour-when-i-open-a-reportviewer-in-wpf)